# Add HTML to single post <head> tag

Tags: html, wp-head

If I have developed a separate HTML page that I wish to include inside my Wordpress site what is the best way of including it?
In this case it requires a javascript library or stylesheet that is not by default in my Wordpress theme that would need to be inserted in the  tag.

I am aware of the following solutions:

iFrames:

- To match the site styling I would need to include every css from the theme in the iframe header.
- If the theme is updated with another script style sheet, this would not be updated in the iframe, maintenance could be arduous.

Editing the theme:

I could add into the various theme files along the lines:

```
is_single( 'page1' )
add_action( 'wp_head', 'extra_stuff' )
```

For each post/page I create or change I would have to change the theme files accordingly.

Ideally I would like to be able to do this from within the post editor

Are there any plugins that accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the best solution was to add a custom field, `head`, and then build a short plugin to add the contents to the head tag:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_HTML_head');
function add_HTML_head(){
    global $post;
    if(!empty($post)){
        // get custom field for 'head'
        $headHTML = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'head', true);
        if(!empty($headHTML)){
            echo $headHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

I've packaged it up into a simple [plugin](http://www.richard-stanton.com/wordpress/wordpress-html/).

Comment: If this answers your own question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of situation you can create a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) for your page, as well as a specific header, for example :

- *template-custompage.php* (your page template)
- *header-custompage.php* (your custom header, where you call your custom CSS and scripts)

In *template-custompage.php*, you call your custom header with :

```
get_header( 'custompage' );
```

Then create your page as you would normally in the Wordpress editor, and choose your custom page template in the pages attributes block.